# Office Script - How to i ) delete a column and ii) find the subtotal of a column based on the column headers?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I am trying to use Office Script to i) delete a column with a header named "Object Type" and
ii) sum up the cells (all the visible filtered cells) in the column named "Hits".

I'm new to Office Script and am stuck. I get the following error for getColumnByName: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getColumnByName')

Any help will be super appreciated!

```
 
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

  let table = workbook.getTables()[0];

//delete a column with a header named "Object Type"
 let rangeObj = table.getColumnByName("Object_Type").getRange();
  selectedSheet.getRange(rangeObj).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.left);

//Sum up the cells  (all the visible filtered cells) in the column named "Hits"
  let rangeHits = table.getColumnByName("Hits").getRange();
  ??? (How to get subtotal based on range selected?)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use `getColumnByName` on a column that's not there (e.g. because it's been deleted) you will get an error. You could also get this error if you have multiple tables in the file and `workbook.getTables()[0]` is returning the wrong table.

For my purposes, I'll assume that the code is throwing an error because the code has been previously run and not because the wrong table is referenced. If that is not correct let me know and I can adjust the code. You can see my code below:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    
      let table = workbook.getTables()[0];
    
      //delete a column with a header named "Object Type"
    
      //added optional chaining so that this line doesn't throw
      //an error if the column has previously been deleted
      table.getColumnByName("Object_Type")?.delete()
    
      //shows the total row for the table
      table.setShowTotals(true)
    
      //sets the rangeHits variable to the rangeHits column in the table
      let rangeHits = table.getColumnByName("Hits");
    
    //Sum up the cells  (all the visible filtered cells) in the column named "Hits"
      rangeHits.getTotalRowRange().setFormulaLocal(`=SUBTOTAL(109,${rangeHits.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getAddress()}`)
    }
```